# Invoicing in classic Asp + Ajax

Tags: asp-classic, invoice

I need to a form for invoicing,

Please help me to have some Idea how to insert all the data at once into invoice table.

I am using text box to get all details for items .

here is the code for get details of items from table.

```
enter code here<% While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT Recordset1.EOF))%>
          <tr>
            <td><input name="dipatchid" type="text" id="dipatchid" value="<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("dispatchid").Value)%>" size="5" /></td>
            <td><input name="dispatchdate" type="text" id="dispatchdate" value="<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("dis_date").Value)%>" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="custid_" id="custid_" />
              <input name="From_" type="text" id="From_" value="<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("from_").Value)%>" /></td>
            <td><input name="to_" type="text" id="to_" value="<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("To_").Value)%>" /></td>
            <td><input name="hrs" type="text" id="hrs" value="<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("total_hrs").Value)%>" size="5" /></td>
            <td><input name="rate_" type="text" id="rate_" size="8" /></td>
            <td><input name="totalamt" type="text" id="totalamt" size="10" /></td>
            <td><img src="imgs/error_icon.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Remove" /></td>              </tr>
          <% Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1  Recordset1.MoveNext() Wend %>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to insert the *Form* data in a database table ? It's not clear what you want to do, exactly.

Comment: Yes, I want to insert the form data to db table,  but the problem is that first I am fetching data from one table to audit... and then post it in other table . And the data is not in fix nos. of rows, its vary

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you will need to keep track of two things:

- the number of rows that are going to be inserted
- the data of each row

Tricks to do this, is simple. While you display your data, you increment a variable with the number of loops.

```
<%
iNumberOfRecords = 0
Do Until Recordset1.EOF
  %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="dipatchid" type="text" id="..." value="<%=Recordset1("dispatchid")%>" />
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <%
  iNumberOfRecords = iNumberOfRecords + 1
Recordset1.MoveNext
loop
Recordset1.Close
%>
```

Before you close your `<form>` tag, you put that in a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="iNumberOfRecords" value="<%=iNumberOfRecords%>" />
```

---

Next, on the page where you submit to, you loop `iNumberOfRecords` times to insert all the rows.

```
<%
for i = 1 to CInt(Request.Form("iNumberOfRecords"))
  idOfRecord = GetFormValue("dipatchid", i)
  otherField = GetFormValue("otherField", i)

  SQL = "INSERT INTO tblInvoices(dispatchid, otherfield) VALUES ( " & idOfRecord & ", " & otherfield & " )"
  Connectionobject.Execute(SQL)
next

Function GetFormValue(sFormname, iIndex)
  If Request.Form(sFormname).Count >= iIndex And iIndex > 0 Then
    GetFormValue = Request.Form(sFormname)(iIndex)
  Else
    GetFormValue = ""
  End If
End Function
%>
```

The `(i)` fetches the right `Request.Form("...")` item for you.

Comment: HI,
Thanks for reply, I got this error
"Request object error 'ASP 0105 : 80004005'

Index out of range

/united/insertinvoice.asp, line 18

An array index is out of range. "


Code is 
"<%

for i = 0 to CInt(Request.Form("iNumberOfRecords"))
  idOfRecord = Request.Form("dipatchid")(i)
  otherField = Request.Form("dispatchdate")(i)
  custid = Request.Form("custid") (i)
  SQL = "INSERT INTO invdat (dispid,disdate,custid) VALUES ( " & idOfRecord & ", " & otherfield & "," & custid & " )"
  Connectionobject.Execute(SQL)
next
%>
"

Comment: Sorry, not working, same error, might be that value we pass to array is big like 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,12,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,21,21,21,1,1,1,121,521,1,1,1,1,522,52,5,11,1,52

Comment: I have edited my code, does this give you any help? Also, if you have a new error, could you please give the line of code where the error occurs?

Comment: error in custid row ,
<%

for i = 1 to CInt(Request.Form("iNumberOfRecords"))
  idOfRecord = Request.Form("dipatchid")(i)
  otherField = Request.Form("dispatchdate")(i)
  custid = Request.Form("custid") (i)
  SQL = "INSERT INTO invdat (dispid,disdate,custid) VALUES ( " & idOfRecord & ", " & otherfield & "," & custid & " )"
  Connectionobject.Execute(SQL)
next
Function GetFormValue(sFormname, iIndex)
  If Request.Form(sFormname).Count >= iIndex And iIndex > 0 Then
    GetFormValue = Request.Form(sFormname)(iIndex)
  Else
    GetFormValue = ""
  End If
End Function

%>